# Angular version upgrade helper tool

Tags: angular, versionupgrade

I have an Angular project with version 16. I want to upgrade it to the latest version. Are there any tools available to indicate depreciated parts and provide new verisons of these parts?

The project is relatively big and I cannot do it manually. I need a half automated tool to help me.